# Custom multiple design tokens

Tags: lightning, community, napili, lightning-community

I have question regarding community. Can I use define custom design tokens per community. 
For example I will have 3 communities and all of them need other custom tokens.

I know that I can solve my problem via custom css.
Is exist any posibility to extends branding tokens per community?

Comment: Based on documentation I see that it has mentioned to create tokens with name as default tokens. It isnt   clear on how to create tokens per community

Comment: hm, 
I check documentation slds
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/#category-font
can I use t(fontFamilyHeading) in my lightning component ?